# Numerical calculation of a double integral from the slowly-decaying oscillating function

Tags: integration, na.numerical-analysis, limits-and-convergence, numerical-integration

Let us consider the following integral
$$
I = \int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}dx\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy \left[f(x,y) + g(x,y) \right].
$$
We know several properties of these functions.

1. There are fixed points $y_i$ such $f(x, y_i)$ is a slowly-decaying function of $x$. Similarly, there are fixed points $x_j$ such $g(x_j, y)$ is a slowly-decaying function of $y$.
2. Functions $f$ and $g$ are analytical in the domain $[0, +\infty) \times (-\infty, +\infty)$.
3. Functions $f$ and $g$ exsist only for $x \geqslant 0$.

The question is, are there methods that allows to efficiently calculate such integrals (for some numerical reasons, it is impossible to consider wide intervals of $x$ and $y$ via applying quadrature methods)?

I'm familiar with the double-exponential transformation (see «The double-exponential transformation in numerical analysis» by Masatake Moria and Masaaki Sugihara).

Is it permissible to apply this procedure to a double integral alternately for $x$ and $y$? And if possible, how to deal with the fact that $f$ and $g$ do not defined for the negative variable $x$?

Comment: You can use the transformation $z=\log(z)$ to map the $x$-integration interval $[0,+\infty)$ to the $z$-integration interval $(-\infty,+\infty)$. Any analytic transformation with the same properties would work too. Now you can apply the double-exponential transformation for both $y$ and $z$ variables in the double integral. This method of numerical integration works based on the Poisson summation formula, which needs some absolute convergence of the original integral. You should check that the "slow decay" of $f$ or $g$ doesn't mess that up.